# Swift: Call closure complete method in a different function

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, closures

I'd like to use a method that return a result asynchronously using the delegate pattern within a closure.

Is it possible to reference the complete block within another function within the same class?

```
class A {

    func performASyncTask(input:String, complete:(result:String) -> Void) {

        let obj = Loader()
        obj.delegate = self
        obj.start()
        // Loader() returns loaderCompleteWithResult(result:String) when completed
    }

    func loaderCompleteWithResult(result:String){

        // Call complete function in performASyncTask .e.g

        complete(result); // Calls the complete function in performASyncTask
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a bit hard to understand, could you elaborate?

Comment: Store the close as a property in the class

Comment: @AMomchilov what specifically do you not understand?

Comment: @dan can you provide an example?

Comment: @xoogler I don't even understand what I don't understand. I assume you want to call `performASyncTask`. You call the closure within that function. What does `obj`? What about the `input` parameter? What's `loaderCompleteWithResult`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't really understand what do you want to achieve. But you can declare function property and use it later:

```
class A {
    var closureSaver: ((result:String) -> Void)?

    func performASyncTask(input:String, complete:(result:String) -> Void) {
        let obj = Loader()
        obj.delegate = self
        obj.start()

        closureSaver = complete
        complete(result: "a")
    }

    func loaderCompleteWithResult(result:String){
        closureSaver?(result:result)
    }
}
```

Comment: Variable names shouldn't be verbs or verb phrases, they should be nouns

Comment: well you are calling completion handler in performASyncTask too which was not what he was looking for